# Merge two columns sum only one column

Tags: pandas, sum

I have a dataframe that looks like this.Is there a way i can combine rows based on EmpID.The only difference will be FunctionName between 2 rows tha i want to combine. I tried groupby and sum but it summmed EmpID and Dept too.Function name will not be required in the output.Output will have new column with total for EmpID

```
print(output.groupby('UserID').sum())

EmpID   UserID   EMPName   Dept MgrName   FunctionName   Problemsolve Lead  Damages sweeper
0121    jon01     jonny    1910  Sam      problemsolve     9.36         0     0       0
0241    matt04    matt     1910  Sam       Lead              0         6.5    0       0
0147    yong21    youn     1920  lisa       Damages          0          0     2.5     0
0147    youn21    youn     1920  lisa       Lead             0         2.5     0      0
```

It should look something like this

```
EmpID   UserID   EMPName    Dept  MgrName  Problemsolve   Lead    Damages  sweeper   Total
 0121    jon01    jonny     1910    Sam        9.36         0       0        0        9.36
 0241    matt04    matt     1910    Sam         0          6.5      0        0         6.5
 0147    yong21    youn     1920    lisa        0          2.5     2.5       0         5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If we name your first dataframe with 4 columns as df, code below will group by the columns that is constant at user level and sum the rest of the columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['EmpID', 'UserID', 'EMPName', 'Dept', 'MgrName']).sum().reset_index()
```

and the code below, will sum up the 4 columns per row and save it in column 'Total:

```
df1['Total'] = df1[['Problemsolve', 'Lead', 'Damages', 'sweeper']].sum(axis=1)
```

I assumed UserID for youn had a typo and made it consistent before running this transformation. If user specific info is not same across rows for the user, it won't be grouped together.